# How to Select a specific name from a group in a table?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

This is my table:
[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6lCK.png)

Now I grouped classes and wanted to select the first_name from each group(class) with the highest marks.

But in class 7 group, I am getting 'edward' instead of 'tony' even though tony has higher marks. how should I order inside a group. I want to order by marks descending.

my output:
[MY output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQzWS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can `order by marks desc` and use `limit 1` only return the first line, which is the row with the highest mark.

```
Select firstname,marks
From student s
Order by marks desc
Limit 1
```